# How to make links from include() file relative to different PHP documents?

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I am setting up my website to use the `include()` statement to standardize things like the header, footer, and navigation, e.g.

`include('header.php);`

However, when I use the same header file for pages in two different directories, the relative links contained within `header.php` break, e.g:

header.php
`<a href="images/dog.jpg">`

index.php
`include('header.php);`
becomes
`<a href="images/dog.jpg">`

This works because that is the correct path to dog.jpg from the index.php file.

animals/canine.php
`include('header.php);`
becomes
`<a href="images/dog.jpg">`

This DOES NOT work because animals/images/dog.jpg does not exist.

So, my question is, what can I change within the header.php file that will tailor the url to dog.jpg to work in both index.php and animals/canine.php when header.php is included?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the includes to use absolute paths:

```
<a href="/images/dog.jpg">
```

This way they'll be based off of the root of your site and always point to the proper folder.

Comment: Superb! I'm using Dreamweaver to do my ftp and I was unsure whether checking 'upload dependent files' for index.php was going to recognize the linked images in header.php as dependent files or external links (which would have to be manually uploaded aside from the page). Turns out Dreamweaver performed the include() upon upload and recognized the linked images as dependent files. All is well!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable called `$root_path` and put into it the path to the root of your web dir relative to the page you're on. Make sure it's declared before you include header.php

This is `mysite.com/junk/index.php` so your image assets are in `../images/`

```
<?php
$root_path = '../'
include('header.php');
```

When outputting your asset urls, put `$root_path` in front of it.